# iterating through all xml elements python

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

I have just started out using python (3.x+) and am trying to figure out how to extract all the elements from an XML file inc all the child nodes (so grand children and great grand children nodes) without doing a check after extracting every child.

I cannot hardcode, as the xml file may change. I simply would like to extract the element, its parent element and if it has any children.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Also see this [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) for the similar lxml module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) module and writing an iterative for loop that can drill down into the nodes in your XML that you'd like extract?

For example, you could do something like this:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse(r'c:\incoming\atom10.xml')  #this is your locally hosted XML file

for index, post in enumerate(d.entries):
    if index >= 5:
        break
    print(post.title) #replace 'title' with the name of the node you want in your XML file, etc 
    print(post.summary)
    print(post.media_keywords)
```

You'll have to play with the script a bit depending upon what you're looking to extract in your XML file. Check the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html) for more details.